# "docker images" retrieves duplicated images with same ID but different tags?

Tags: docker, duplicates

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              14f60031763d        2 weeks ago         119.5 MB
ubuntu              <none>              14f60031763d        2 weeks ago         119.5 MB
```

Comment: Every image you pull gets the tag `<none>`? Which version of docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all dangling images with [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Why is this happening? I can't really think of a good reason. What actions lead to this?

Answer (score 0):

'Docker images' command will display all the images including the old versions. 
That's default behaviour. 
However, you can use filters to list specific images, I cannot see any direct command to list only latest images.

You can also try like this,
For example, docker images java:8
which will give you the image of java with version 8.